# Architecture for a lot of data logging, DB or file?

Tags: python, mongodb, logging

I'm working on a Python app I want to be scalable to accommodate about 150 writes per second.  That's spread out among about 50 different sources.

Is Mongodb a good candidate for this?  I'm split on writing to a database, or just making a log file for each source and parsing them separately.

Any other suggestions for logging a lot of data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say that mongodb very good fit for the logs collection, because of:

1. Mongodb has amazing **fast writes**
2. Logs not so important, so it's okay to loose some of them in case of server failure. So you can run mongodb **without [journaling](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Journaling)** option to avoid writes overhead.
3. In additional you can use **sharding** to increase writes speed, in same time you can just move oldest logs to **separate collection** or into file system.
4. You can **easy** [export](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Import+Export+Tools#ImportExportTools-mongoimport) data from database to the json/csv.
5. Once you will have everything in a database you will able to **query data** in order to find log that you need.

So, my opinion is that mongodb perfectly fit for such things as logs. You no need manage a lot of logs files in the file system. Mongodb does this for you.

Comment: +1. I think 5) is the most important argument: you really want to be able to analyze your logs. In a larger app, log files are worthless because you can't read individual lines unless you're tracking errors. I'd also suggest to not only log text, but some meaningful data as well (e.g. user id, server name, module id, etc.)

Comment: @mnemosyn: i agree, i am logging everything: request details, user info, exception details, etc.. :). admin panel of app on what i am working on show today's logs by default and have a lot of filter fields, paging, etc.

Comment: @everyone thanks guys. i set it up and it was amazingly painless. i gotta check into the journaling feature.

Comment: @AndrewOrsich You may also want to add points about "Capped Collections", their write performance, and circular queue behaviour.