# Storing and Analyzing Logs Database Selection

Tags: mysql, mongodb, logging, database

I am building an internal tool, which will be open-sourced, to take logs and put them into a database - to put it simply. From there, the tool will also analyze the logs and help alert the sys-admins and developers of issues going on, all in real-time. This is a lot of CPU to process this, more than the scope of this question.

What I would like to know is what Database to choose that will allow and perform quickly a number of key tasks:

- Store a large number of events categorized by event types
- Perform a large number of reads to develop charts to analyze the events that are being logged
- Read in real-time to send and trigger automated alerts to the system.

And any other help would be greatly appreciated, too. Code On.

Comment: Mongodb should be good solution for this, take a look into [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336418/architecture-for-a-lot-of-data-logging-db-or-file/8337547#8337547) about logging in mongodb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my observation MongoDB performs in a magnitude better than RDBS for a task you describe - massive store of logs. Particularly good performers are capped collections. Major performance lag with RDBS I've seen was the insert times. Huge disadvantage of RDBS is the schema which is a major pain to upgrade if needed. Because of these reasons we have started to move towards MongoDB - check out [logFaces](http://www.logfaces.com). If you are building your own tool for the open source community - try to make sure it will work with ANY database, not just a particular brand. But then it becomes a not so trivial task :)

(for disclosure - I am the original author of logFaces, so the opinion could be biased)

Answer (score 1):

Storing just events sound like a simple model, so you might want to take a look at *NoSQL* databases. I think key-value stores/bigtables for really large amounts of data will be better than document based databases in this case.

Large number of reads and analysing on the other hand sound like you might want to build a *data warehouse system*. This is the good old SQL approach, without some normalization for optimised reading. Though it can take some time to design and implement.

Comment: This actually that leads to the question whether you can combine both concepts. I haven't found an answer to that. I really would like to know, as I am building a similar system too, which could be described with the same (vague) words as in the question.

Comment: I was looking into MongoDB for a NoSQL solution.